# Where is my Tomcat running?

Tags: linux, tomcat, path, directory

I am using linux centos. I have installed tomcat in multiple folders. One of them is running.
When I use `netstat -ntlp` command, it says port 8080 is running, and I can access the URL `http://localhost:8080`

Now I want to know the path of tomcat folder where it's running?

Assume I closed all the terminals, I could not guess where I initiated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you don't know I don't see how you could expect us to.

Comment: @MikeW Very nice reply..

Answer (score 1):

do a ps -ef grep for tomcat
the result will have the directory of tomcat

```
   [user@edw-support-dev1 ~]$ ps -ef | grep tomcat
    root     12898     1  0 May14 ?        00:30:38 /usr/local/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1536m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/endorsed -classpath /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
    2064     21567 21544  0 21:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep tomcat
```

Comment: It only shows me  2064     21567 21544  0 21:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep tomcat. I don't see previous line

Comment: @Hideandseek it probably means that your tomcat is not running now.

Answer (score 0):

ps aux | grep tomcat

And you will know the installation directory of tomcat.

You can also use "locate" command as "locate tomcat" this command will find out the files named tomcat which might give you a pointer where tomcat is residing on your disk. :)